# Send html table to controller in MVC by ajax As JSON Object in datatable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, ajax, datatables

I'm using the dataTables jQuery plugin , but I'm having trouble

Reference to below link i can download the table as JSON,

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/customFile.html

But in my case i want to save the table as JSOn in variable to send it to controller by use Angular or JQuery AJAX

I can do that by using tableToJSON Library but i will store the showing row only in current page not the full rows

```
{ var table = $('#datatable').tableToJSON();}
```

Comment: How are you populating the table in first place? Are you not using JSON?

Comment: by using foreach in Database Model

Comment: Try  $('#datatable').dataTable( {    
    "bRetrieve": true
  } );

Answer (score 0):

If you're using client-side processing, you can retrieve data for the whole table simply by using [`data()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()) API method.

```
var data = $('#datatable').DataTable().data();
```

Comment: thank you for your comment ,, but unfortunately its doesn't work with me